# How to make a page shows products in the right order using php, ajax, jquery and a dropdown menu

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am trying to make a dropdown menu from which you can sort a page "price high-low" or "price low-high".

This is the HTML with an id="show_product"

```
<div class="row" id ="notification-bar"></div>
<div class="row" id="show_product">Here comes the table with products</div>
```

This is the HTML for the dropdown menu:

```
<select name="sort" id="sort">
    <option value="asc">Price low - high</option>
    <option value="desc">Price high - low</option>
</select>
```

The Jquery for this is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#sort').change(function() {      
        var sort = $(this).val();               
        $.ajax({
            url:"load_products.php",
            method:"POST",
            data: {sort:sort},
            succes:function(data){
                $('#notification-bar').text('The page has been successfully loaded');
                $('#show_product').html(data);
           },
           error: function() {
               $('#notification-bar').text('An error occurred');
           }
        });     
    });
});
```

And finaly the load_products.php is:

```
<?php
include("inc/connect.php");

$output = '';

if($_POST["sort"] != '') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM shop ORDER BY price " . $_POST["sort"];
    $result   = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">';
        $output .= '<div class="single-product">';
        $output .= '<img class="img-fluid" src="' . $row["imageURL"] . '">';
        $output .= '<div class="product-details">';
        $output .= '<h6 class="text-center">' . $row["title"] . '</h6>';
        $output .= '<div class="price text-center">';
        $output .= '<h6>&euro; ' . $row["price"] . '</h6>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }   
    return $output;
} else {
    $query  = "SELECT * FROM shop ORDER BY price ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $output .= '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">';
        $output .= '<div class="single-product">';
        $output .= '<img class="img-fluid" src="' . $row["imageURL"] . '">';
        $output .= '<div class="product-details">';
        $output .= '<h6 class="text-center">' . $row["title"] . '</h6>';
        $output .= '<div class="price text-center">';
        $output .= '<h6>&euro; ' . $row["price"] . '</h6>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';
    }   
    return $output;         
}   
?>
```

The problem is that when I change the option from the dropdown, the ID "show_product" isn't filled with the data from load_products.php.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Kind regards,

Arie

Comment: is this column exists `prijs`?

Comment: **Warning!** You are _wide open_ to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection)! **_Never_** use user data directly in your queries like that. Use parameterized [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: your first step should be to add an error callback to your ajax function to display any errors. Also you use "ORDER BY price" in your first statement and "ORDER BY prijs" in the second.

Comment: Instead of `return $output`, try `echo $output;`

Comment: @DrakulaPredatorم Sorry for the mistake, prijs must be price, I just changed it

Comment: So is it  working Now?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to get it work, have added a error callback, I see now that I have a success callback ($('#notification-bar').text('The page has been successfully loaded');) but the id #show_product doesn't changes so I think $('#show_product').html(data); doesn't give the right response

Answer (score 0):

Well I could not see your form method but I hope u check for little things like is set to POST. Also yes if you not using OOP way try to sanitized inputs.
Enable show errors in PHP.ini as this helps us too if you showed us exact display of effect when code runs.